# Associate multiple properties in advanced search in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I've successfully added a custom form to the advanced search interface in Alfresco, but I'm facing a problem. Here's my custom form (`search-config-custom.xml`):

```
<config evaluator="model-type" condition="cv:document">
   <forms>
      <form id="search">
         <field-visibility>
            <show id="cv:appl_name" />
            <show id="cv:appl_surn" />
            <show id="cv:appl_phone" />
            <show id="cv:appl_lang_1" />
            <show id="cv:appl_level_1" />
            <show id="cv:appl_lang_2" />
            <show id="cv:appl_level_2" />
            <show id="cv:appl_lang_3" />
            <show id="cv:appl_level_3" />
         </field-visibility>
      </form>
   </forms>
</config>
```

The form is basically querying information regarding job applicants. Applicants can enter up to three foreign languages in their profile, and assign a level of proficiency to them.

Now, here's the problem: let's say a recruiter wants to search for candidates with a high level of Spanish. As I have my form now, they would have to enter "Spanish" in the three language fields in order to get reliable results, as it's not known beforehand the order in which candidates entered their languages, if any.

So, I'm looking for a way to have a field that can automatically search across all the different language fields, so that instead of having "Language 1", "Language 2" and "Language 3", I can simply have "Languages" as a single search field. Then, language fields should be associated with their respected levels, and I really don't know how to do this.

Here's the content model the custom search form is querying:

```
<types>
   <type name="cv:document">
      <title>Job Application</title>
      <parent>cm:content</parent>

      <properties>
         <property name="cv:appl_name">
            <title>Applicant's first name</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
         <property name="cv:appl_surn">
            <title>Applicant's last name</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
            <property name="cv:appl_phone">
            <title>Applicant's phone number</title>
         <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
            <property name="cv:appl_lang_1">
            <title>Language 1</title>
         <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
         <property name="cv:appl_level_1">
            <title>Level for Language 1</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
         <property name="cv:appl_level_2">
            <title>Level for Language 2</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
         </property>
         <property name="cv:appl_level_3">
            <title>Level for Language 3</title>
            <type>d:text</type>
         </property>        
      </properties>
   </type>
</types>
```

I'm running Alfresco 5.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit your SOLR schema to add a new SOLR field which would be filled with all languages. Then you'd query against that single field.

For example.

```
<field  name="all" type="text___" indexed="true" omitNorms="false"  stored="false"  multiValued="true" />
<copyField source="*" dest="all" />
```